# Use ToString or Value to get string value of an xml doc

Tags: c#, xml

If I have a `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, and I return the value of it, would I get the literal string value of the entire doc?

Or do I need to use ToString for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should start by reading the documentation of [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

It will show you that you can use the [`OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) property.

> Gets the markup representing this node and all its child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have -

```
XmlDocument doc;
```

that contains valid XML,

you can get its XML string using -

```
XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;
Console.WriteLine(root.FirstChild.OuterXml);
```